# how to forward request to docker machine in local network in OSX

Tags: macos, docker, nat, portforwarding

I am currently running a docker machine in local network that its IP & port is 192.168.99.100:8080
right now. I want to connect this machine from somewhere out of the local network and access it, so the best way I found is to NAT the sent request from my laptop computer to docker machine. 
In other words, each request that has been sent to my laptop computer will be sent to the docker machine on its own IP and port!
I use pfctl to do this but when I check the port 8585 to find out which service is listening to this port, I can't find anything and it sounds like the requests do not arrive(get to) the destination!

I did as below:

1- csrutil disable

2- my pf role : 
/etc/pf.anchors/mazafard:

```
rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.20.203 port 8585 -> 192.168.99.100 port 8080
```

3- my pf conf
/etc/pf-mazafard.conf

```
rdr-anchor "forwarding"
load anchor "forwarding" from "/etc/pf.anchors/mazafard"
```

and

```
sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/mazafard


pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.20.203 port = 8585 -> 192.168.99.100 port 8080
```

and

```
sudo pfctl -evf /etc/pf.anchors/mazafard


fctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.20.203 port = 8585 -> 192.168.99.100 port 8080
pfctl: pf already enabled
```

and

```
telnet 192.168.20.203 8585

Trying 192.168.20.203...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.20.203: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

My OSX v: 10.11.4

Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5

Boot2Docker version 1.11.0-rc3, build

Comment: Since the vm is a VirtualBox vm, you can just use VirtualBox's port forwarding.

Comment: why you use docker ?

Comment: Any success yet?